# Access and set the value of non standard attributes with hyphens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gridstack

I'm trying read and write values of non standard attributes with hyphens in the name.  These attributes are being created by a library called gridstack, so I cant just use data- atttributes.

As an example,  I have an element with the following content;

```
<div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable" gs-x="0" gs-y="0" gs-w="1" gs-h="4" gs-id="4">...</div>;
```

I'm attempting to read/set the gs-h attribute.

So these do not work;

```
// Element is just the dom object containing the above div.
var element = $('#dPanel' + id)[0].parentNode.parentNode; 

var h = element.getAttribute('gs-h'); // Doesnt work
var h = $(element).attr('gs-h');      // Doesnt work
$(element).attr('gs-h', '1');         // Doesnt work
```

I could just yank the value out by parsing the innerHtml, but that does not let me set the value.

Comment: What does `element` refer to? please show us all relevant code

Comment: [Accessing the value seems to work fine](https://jsbin.com/bacegus/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Are you sure `element` is referring to the correct element?, also `.att('gs-h', '1')` is wrong

Comment: I've been staring at this problem too long.  I was returning the element from another function - but that function returned it inside an object with some other data.  And I didnt unwrap it.  Sorry for wasting your time, I assumed it was due to the hyphen and didnt look closely enough.

Comment: $(element).attr('gs-h', '1') was a typo when I posted.  I'll update the post, but it works, the intent was to set the attribute.

Comment: @ThereandThat `.att(` should be `.attr(` so it's indeed wrong.

Comment: Next time.. copy/paste ;)

Comment: If either of you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.  It was VLAZ who proved I messed up though.  I'd been backwards and forwards for an hour trying to figure out why it wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

for vanilla js, might try the DOM property [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) :

> The `Element.attributes` property returns a live collection of all attribute nodes registered to the specified node. It is a `NamedNodeMap`, not an `Array` ...

e.g. to retrieve the value of a non-standard attribute `url` of a `<a>` element, just simply do like

```
const url = element.attributes['url'].nodeValue
```